# Stirling numbers of the second kind -- a series-expansion typo?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

In H. S. Wilf's *generatingfunctionology*, (1.6.8) describes:

$$
A_n(y) = \sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k-1\end{Bmatrix} y^k + \sum \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix} y^k
$$
$$
= yA_{n-1}(y) + \left( y \frac{d}{dy} \right) A_{n-1}(y)
$$

where

$$
A_n(y) = \sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix} y^k
$$

but surely if

$$
A_{n-1}(y) = \sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix} y^k = \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\1\end{Bmatrix}y + \ldots + \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix}y^k
$$
then 
$$
A_n(y) = \left (yA_{n-1}(y) - \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix} y^{k+1} \right)+ y \frac{d}{dy} A_{n-1}(y)
$$

since $A_n(y)$ only sums over $k$ rather than $k+1$. So is this a typo or am I missing something? This is also somewhat important as the author uses this as an example further on to describe other important things.

(I also can't seem to find the errata for the book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it seems like you've confused what the author means by $\sum_k f(k)$.  That is, $$\sum_k f(k) \neq f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(k)$$
Rather:
$$\sum_k f(k) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} f(k) = f(0) + f(1) + f(-1) + f(2) + f(-2) + \cdots$$

(See Convention 1.3.)

Taking into account that $\begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix} = 0$ if $k > n$ or $n,k<0$, we can see that:
\begin{align}
A_n(y) &= \sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n\\k\end{Bmatrix}y^k = \begin{Bmatrix}n\\0\end{Bmatrix} + \begin{Bmatrix}n\\1\end{Bmatrix}y +\cdots + \begin{Bmatrix}n\\n\end{Bmatrix}y^n\\
\implies A_{n-1}(y) &= \sum_k \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\k\end{Bmatrix}y^k = \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\0\end{Bmatrix} + \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\1\end{Bmatrix}y +\cdots + \begin{Bmatrix}n-1\\n-1\end{Bmatrix}y^{n-1}\\
\end{align}

With this, the formulas become readily apparent.

Comment: As an aside: there are way too few questions asked here about *generatingfunctionology*.  It's an awesome book.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I've been jumping between books as of late and it was only a matter of time before I forgot about some of his notation.

And yes, it's been an amazing book so far. Every other page reminds me of those "one weird trick" scams except I am left satisfied.

Comment: @Soyuz Yep. :) To me, notation is the hardest part of mathematics.  Once I can figure out what an author means by his/her symbols, I can "see" everything quite clearly.